# Split an integer number into digits non-backward

Tags: c++

I am looking for an efficient and simple way to separate an integer into digits, but I need to separate them starting from the first one.

Here's the typical way to sepparate a number into digits:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { //argc is going to be the number
    while(argc != 0) {
        cout << argc % 10 << endl;
        argc /= 10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But doing it this way I will obtain, for example, 5437 -> 7,3,4,5
I want to reverse the order of appereance, 5,4,3,7. So I created this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int rem = 1;

    while(argc / rem > 10) //We increase the remainder until we get the same amount of digits than the number
        rem *= 10;

    while(argc != 0) {
        cout << argc / rem << endl; //We take the cocient of the division, wich will be always the first digit
        argc %= rem; //Now we discard that digit
        rem /= 10; //And we decrease the number of digits of the remainder too
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is: is there any alternative way to do this in a shorter/simpler way?

PS: I can't use stacks, lists or that kind of structures.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Recursion is another way.

Comment: I typically just have an array to store in, and then print it forwards.

Comment: I can't imagine having to limit oneself from using stacks or lists, unless assembly language was the real target. In the 6502 there were various tricks one could use with decimal mode. In multiple machines which lacked native divide instructions there was a trick involving a shift by three bits and adding either 3 or 6 depending on when you did the add. The significance of 6 is that it is of course the difference between 10 and 16. Mohammad's answer seems like the one you should use even though "technically" the array is a stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use some string methods .For instance you can convert your number to a string .Therefor, you can use string splitters functions.
of course you can use below sample code

```
#define MaxDigits 8

void SplitDigits(int Number, int* DigitArray)
{
   for(int i=(MaxDigits-1); i>=0; i++)
   {
      DigitArray[i] = Number % 10;
      Number /= 10;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int DigitArray[MaxDigits];
   int Number = 1538;

   SplitDigits(Number, DigitArray);

   for(int i=0; i<MaxDigits; i++)
   {
      cout << DigitArray[i] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be recursion:

```
int index=0, result[100];

void digits(int x) {
    if (x > 10) digits(x/10);
    result[index++] = x % 10;
}
```

(it would use an implicit stack, however)

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned n = 123450;
unsigned m = 0, k = 1;
while (n != 0) {
    m = m * 10 + n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    k++;
}
while (--k > 0) {
    cout << m % 10 << endl;
    m /= 10;
}
```

Comment: It is an incorrect approach because you will not get trailing zeroes. For example for number 10 you will get just 1 instead of 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would convert the **int** to a **string**, go through each **char** and convert that back to an **int**, while storing that newly created **int** in a **vector**. This may be a lot more complicated than it has to be, but I find it easier. Mostly because I already made functions that convert a digit to string and vice versa. I'm sure this isn't an efficient way of doing it either, but it works.

Here's how I just did it (note that this could all be done in a single function):

```
// convert an int to a string representation
string intToString(const int& digit)
{
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << digit;
    return oss.str();
}

// if possible, convert characters in string to integer value
int stringToInt(const string& str)
{
    istringstream iss{ str };
    int digit;
    iss >> digit;
    if (!iss)
        throw runtime_error{ "integer format error: " + str};
    return digit;
}

// split an int into its seperate digits and store them in a vector
vector<int> splitInteger(const int& digit)
{
    vector<int> splits;     // holds the ints that are split from the original
    const string s = intToString(digit);
    for (char ch : s) {
        const string temp{ ch };    // convert char to string for use with stringToInt()
        splits.push_back(stringToInt(temp));
    }
    return splits;
}
```

You might also want to name things better than I did, if you do go this route. I'm terrible at quickly naming things. :)

So here's a simple way of using splitInteger():

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    vector<int> splits = splitInteger(num);

    for (const int& i : splits)
        cout << i << '\n';

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```